# Duplicity Errno 2 - no such file or directory

Tags: debian, samba, cifs, duplicity

I am trying to setup a script for backing up a linux box to a CIFS share.

I manually mounted the CIFS share and created a few test folders - OK
I then ran duplicity manually with a rather simple command to begin with to make sure things work and well Not OK on this one :)

```
duplicity /root file:///cifsmountfolder/existingfolder/

results:
No signatures found, switching to full backup.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 463, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 458, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 449, in main
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 155, in full_backup
    bytes_written = write_multivol("full", tarblock_iter, globals.backend)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 99, in write_multivol
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/duplicity/backends.py", line 279, in put
    target_path.writefileobj(source_path.open("rb"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 500, in writefileobj
    fout = self.open("wb")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/duplicity/path.py", line 448, in open
    else: result = open(self.name, mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/cifsmountfolder/existingfolder/duplicity-full.2010-09-18T18:41:43-07:00.vol1.difftar.gpg'
```

any ideas?

Thank you.

Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When mounting cifs, use the mapchars option, which will enable duplicity to write the colon (:) characters that are included in its file naming convention.

See http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html for all options.

Comment: The other option is to use the "--old-filenames" option which uses filenames that are compatible with windows shares.

Answer (score 0):

That really looks like it just cannot write to that folder.  What does `touch /cifsmountfolder/existingfolder/test` do?

Comment: works fine, I can create files, more folders, edit files, delete files, delete fodlers etc. Thanks

Comment: That's pretty mysterious.  I would try running `strace duplicity ...` with the same arguments to confirm it is the `open` syscall that's failing and perhaps to get some more data why.